# Pass String Array from Fragment to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Please need help if you know how to Pass String Array from Fragment to MainActivity ?

String[] name

String[] firstname

Here is my Fragment Code :

```
public class PersonFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_NAME = "name";
private static final String ARG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";

ListView lst;


String[] name = {"Dockar","Nilson"};

String[] firstname = {"Jack","Michel"};


public static PersonFragment newInstance(String[] name, String[] firstname) {
    PersonFragment fragment = new PersonFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray(ARG_NAME, name);
    args.putStringArray(ARG_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;

}

Activity mainActivity;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_fragment, container, false);

    lst = view.findViewById(R.id.listviewperson);
    CustomeListviewAdapterTest customeListview = new CustomeListviewAdapterTest(this.mainActivity,name,firtname);
    lst.setAdapter(customeListview);

    lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            if(position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Jack.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }if(position == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Michel.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } 
        }
    });

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        name = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_NAME);
        firstname = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_FIRSTNAME);

    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Here i call my fragment from MainActivity but i can't/don't know to put it :( in the newInstance:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.drawer_person:
            PersonFragment fragment = PersonFragment.newInstance(????????????????);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            break;
```

}

Or is there mistake on my code ? I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: I think you should use ```Viewmodel``` to manage data on one place for ```Activity``` and ```Fragment```

Comment: Use Sharedpreference to save it and access it from anywhere